# Automatic SVN builds to use parameters

Tags: svn, parameters, hudson, jenkins, testng

I'm a SW Tester and we're using jenkins for CI. I'm using TestNG and
I have a parameter, which specifies a TestSuite to be ran.
So in my pom.xml I have the following:

```
<suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/${testSuite}</suiteXmlFile>
```

We have various TestSuites, like SmokeTest.xml, Integration.xml and so on..
For manual build-requests, I set up a parameter DropDown to chose the *.xml file I want to run.

But how can I specify a standard value, which will be used for every SVN-triggered build?

I tried setting up `"testSuite=SmokeTest.xml"` in the Configure-tab of the project, but that way it always uses SmokeTest.xml and ignores the chosen value from the DropDown :(

Thanks a lot

Comment: For your mentoined integration test you should use the integration-test life-cycle phase of maven (which looks like a maven build) and don't use a parameter for that. The other might be the best to use a profile for that. But you gave not much information about that.

Comment: @khmarbaise I agree that this might not be the best way to approach integration-testing (and we do that on other environments). Maybe that was a bad example. So in particular, I have multiple Test-sets, specified as TestSuites in their respective *.xml.
As default, I want to run a smoketest-suite (after every svn-change, which triggers an automatic build) - But I also want to run special suites on demand

Comment: Based on what i can see is that you seemed to be using TestNG why not using groups for that kind of purpose. Furthermore you can define the groups and define the configuration for maven-surefire as well as for maven-failsafe into a particular profile which should solve that problem.

Comment: Alright, I'll have a look at that :)

Comment: Have you given a name for the drop-down-parameter and used that parameter in the calling of mvn like mvn -DsuiteXmlFiles=${DROPDOW} ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that jenkins uses the first line of the DropDown-values as default. So I added Regression.xml in the first line and the other values underneath.

This way, Regression.xml automatically gets triggered after a svn update (or after pre-projects have been rebuild), but I still have the chance to run other tests on demand.